# react state is not updating the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Form Component where it contains a state that should be updated (on input change) and it looks like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Test = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: 'khaled',
    age: 18
})

const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let stateCopy = state 

    for(let key in stateCopy) {
        if(key === 'name') {
            stateCopy[key] = e.target.value;
        }
    }

    setState(stateCopy);
}


return(
    <div>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input onChange={ handleInputChange } />
        <span>{state.name}</span>
    </div>
)
}
```

and it imported in the app component

```
import { Test } from '../../components/Test';

function App() {
  return (
    <Test />
  );
}

export default App;
```

and whenever i try to change the name inout it not update the ui

Comment: stateCopy is actually not a copy. Your assigning the state as is. Therefore is still the same reference and React assumes the object has not changed. let stateCopy = {...state} should do the trick. Btw. you can useState for each of the properties separately. Like const [name, setName] = useState('khaled'); const [age, setAge] = useState(18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the input a controlled component, both `value` and `onChange` props should be assigned.

```
<input value={state.name} onChange={handleInputChange} />
```

`handleInputChange` function can be improved to make sure that the state is updated immutably:

```
const handleInputChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setState(prevState => ({...prevState, name: value}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because your "stateCopy" object isn't actually a copy, its the actual state object. you are setting the state to the same object which causes react to think the state didn't change at all.

instead you should copy the state like this

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let stateCopy = {...state}
    state.name = e.target.value

    setState(stateCopy);
}
```

You should also note that unless there is a good reason for your choice of state in my opinion you should use a seperate useState for each element in the state which results in the much simpler

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Test = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('khalad')
const [age, setAge] = useState(18)

const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
}

return(
    <div>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input onChange={ handleInputChange } />
        <span>{state.name}</span>
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply do it like this, it will work

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
       
setState({...state, name: e.target.value})
        
}
```